# how to extract a value from a variable and put a new one in its place?

Tags: rust

As a beginner in rust I am trying to implement basic data structures. Here I am trying to implement a stack. Here are the structs I am using

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Node<T: std::marker::Copy> {
    value: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T: std::marker::Copy> Node<T> {
    fn new(value: T) -> Node<T> {
        Node { value, next: None }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Stack<T: std::marker::Copy> {
    first: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    last: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    size: usize,
}
```

Now, in `push()` function, what I'm trying to do is, if there is no `first` and `last`, put the newly created `Node` as the new `first` and `last`. If they exist already, create a new variable `temp` which holds the current `first`, put the new `Node` as the new value in `first`, and put the previous `first`'s `next` value as `temp`. Here is my `push()`.

```rust
impl<T: std::marker::Copy> Stack<T> {
    fn push(&mut self, elem: T) -> usize {
        if self.first.is_none() {
            self.first = Some(Box::new(Node::new(elem)));
            self.last = Some(Box::new(Node::new(elem)));
        } else {
            let temp = self.first.take();
            self.first = Some(Box::new(Node::new(elem)));
            self.first.unwrap().next = Some(Box::new(*temp.unwrap())); //problem in this line
        }
        self.size += 1;
        self.size
    }
}
```

Here when I'm trying to assign the `next` value, I'm getting the error

```
cannot move out of `self.first` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/bin/stack.rs:36:13
   |
36 |             self.first.unwrap().next = Some(Box::new(*temp.unwrap()));
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.first` has type `Option<Box<Node<T>>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
help: consider borrowing the `Option`'s content
   |
36 |             self.first.as_ref().unwrap().next = Some(Box::new(*temp.unwrap()));
   |                       +++++++++
```

Using `as_ref()` further increases the error as it can't assign data in a refernce. How can I correct this and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would consider using an [Arena](https://docs.rs/indextree/latest/indextree/struct.Arena.html) which makes the handling of a Node much less complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for `std::mem::replace` https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html

It allows you to replace the data pointed to by a `&mut T` with a `T`, and returns the original data as an owned `T`.

For example:

```rust
let mut s = String::from("hello");
let new_str = String::from("new");

let old_str: String = std::mem::replace(&mut s, new_str);

assert_eq!(s, "new");
assert_eq!(old_str, "hello");
```

P.S why not use a `Vec<T>` (unless you're using a linked list for learning purposes). It has a simple API, and performance will be significantly better in the vast majority of cases

P.P.S. If you're implementing a linked list for learning purposes, check out https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: Everyone advises against using lists but i dont think something should be avoided just because the compiler doesn't likes it.

Comment: The reasons for avoiding linked lists are more than just "the compiler doesn't like it". Generally, given modern CPU architecture, they perform significantly worse than contiguous arrays (other than fairly niche cases where you prefer the properties of a linked list). Having said that "Learning Rust with Too Many Linked Lists"  is a great resource for learning more about the language, and there's nothing wrong with implementing one yourself as a learning exercise

Comment: @Alonzo The compiler doesn't like it for a reason - the things that linked lists are good at modeling (partly shared ownership) are precisely the things that Rust's borrow checker is designed to prevent. In addition, many people misuse linked lists for things where a vector would suffice, simply by habit carried over from C-like languages, where a linked list was the easiest dynamic container to implement.

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is a better way but I used a combination of `RefCell` and `std::mem:replace` to get around the error, wrapping your fields with `RefCell` will allow you to get *mutable reference* that you can then  pass to replace to perform the memory change. Here is the code

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::mem::replace;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Node<T: std::marker::Copy> {
    value: T,
    next: RefCell<Option<Box<Node<T>>>>,
}

impl<T: std::marker::Copy> Node<T> {
    fn new(value: T) -> Node<T> {
        Node { value, next: RefCell::new(None) }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Stack<T: std::marker::Copy> {
    first: RefCell<Option<Box<Node<T>>>>,
    last: RefCell<Option<Box<Node<T>>>>,
    size: usize,
}
impl<T: std::marker::Copy> Stack<T> {
    fn push(&mut self, elem: T) -> usize {
        if self.first.borrow().is_none() {
            self.first = RefCell::new(Some(Box::new(Node::new(elem))));
            self.last = RefCell::new(Some(Box::new(Node::new(elem))));
        } else {
            let temp =replace(self.first.get_mut(),None);
            self.first = RefCell::new(Some(Box::new(Node::new(elem))));
            let _=replace(self.first.get_mut(), Some(Box::new(*temp.unwrap())));
        }
        self.size += 1;
        self.size
    }
}
```